# Does toString create a new object when we call it on a String?

Tags: java, string

I was discussing String with my friend and came to know that calling `toString()` on a String creates new object? But even my friend doesn't know the reason. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The source code is freely available.

Comment: You might read the documentation, the source code, evaluate `someString == someString.toString()` or… just ask here.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch That is a great point about testing with `==`. [Here is the proof.](http://ideone.com/fWSNLJ)

Answer (score 8):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString%28%29) states

> This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.

**so, no, it doesn't create a new object.** Instead, a reference to the same object is returned. It could be (and is) implemented as

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

Note that `String` is immutable so it's a non-issue.